# Using precompiled headers in msvc when building from the command line with the cl compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio, precompiled-headers, cl

Edit: I know how to use it in VS, and CMake, I am trying to find out how to do it using cl.exe on the command line and not from inside the Visual Studio IDE or using a build generator like CMake.

Original question:
I am trying to use precompiled headers on windows with MSVC. mainly to bundle all Microsoft's headers in one place and precompile them for faster compile builds.

The problem is I can not figure out how to actually use pch files.
I was trying following the two links from the official documentation:
[Create Precompiled Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/yc-create-precompiled-header-file?view=msvc-170)
and also this:
[Use Precompiled Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/yu-use-precompiled-header-file?view=msvc-170)

I am generating the .pch file are follows:

```
cl /c /Ycheaders.h main.cpp
```

inside **headers.h** I do the following:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
//--- other includes that will never change ----//
```

And following the documentation this is how I try to use it.

```
cl /Yuheaders.h main.cpp
```

this get me the following error:
**fatal error C1854: cannot overwrite information formed during creation of the precompiled header in object main.obj**

I assumed the documentation is wrong (because the provided command in the docs: cl /Ycheader.h main.cpp is wrong and does not work and it needs /c before it as in the comment in the example code), It did not make sense to me to compile your **main.cpp**  so I repeated the steps above with creating the precompiled headers files with **headers.cpp** instead of **main.cpp** where **headers.cpp** is just an empty source file with a single include **headers.h** and the I get a linking error **1 unresolved external LINK error 1120** without specifying what was unresolved.

Ideally if anyone has a minimal example of how to create header files for msvc and then shows how to use them.

Comment: Step generating precompiled header should use different .cpp file name. `cl /c /Ycheaders.h precompiled.cpp`

Comment: @user7860670 I just tried it, did not work. do you have a full minimal example of how to use /Yc and then /Yu? because generating the headers works, but using them is where the issue happens

Comment: In your second attempt, since `headers.cpp` will make `headers.pch`, did you use `/Fpheaders.pch` for your `cl /Yuheaders.h /Fpheaders.pch main.cpp`?  Another MSDN [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/creating-precompiled-header-files?view=msvc-170) of using PCH.

Comment: @Eljay yes I tried that, and it is still the same issue "error LNK2011: precompiled object not linked in fatal error LINK1120 1 unresolved externals"

Comment: @Serilena: Generating the headers works - also with `headers.cpp`. I checked the documentation, it is correct. You're going to get `headers.pch`, and that will be used by `/Yuheaders.h`. If you forgot something in `headers.h`, then yes, you can get errors.

Comment: I just tried the experiment.  (Took long because updates to MSVC.)  I followed the MSDN directions, and making and using a PCH worked for me from the command line.

Comment: @Eljay can you post your commands? like how did you compile them? and how did you use them?

Comment: @MSalters I am just asking what did you pass to the compiler to generate them and what did you pass to the compiler to use them, that would help me to compare with what I have to see what went wrong on my end.

Comment: @Serilena: From my current project: `/Yc"pch.h"` for `pch.cpp`, `/Yu"pch.h"` for every other .cpp file.

Comment: Well, again this is exactly what I did: 
`cl /c /Ycpch.h pch.cpp` followed by `cl /Yupch.h main.cpp` and I got the error I posted above

Comment: In that example `pch.cpp` needs to be part of the Visual Studio project.

Comment: but I am not using visual studio @drescherjm I specifically asked for `cl.exe` and not via a build system, because I can use cmake just fine and be done with it. CMake uses /FI to force the include which is not what docs say. I am asking specifically about `cl.exe` way

Comment: `cl /EHsc /c /Ycheader.hpp header.cpp` and `cl /EHsc /Yuheader.hpp /Fpheader.pch main.cpp header.obj`

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT no, I tried the code by Eljay above and it was the same error, I updated, reinstalled Windows/VS and still nothing changed, same exact error.

Comment: Can you provide your command line screenshot without personal privacy?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT I suspect it was a problem with my installation of VS/AntiVirus stuff.
not entirely sure, but when I installed VS the other day I had some antivirus threat warnings. I disabled it, reinstalled VS and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create pch:

```
cl /EHsc /c /Ycheader.h header.cpp
```

Use pch:

```
cl /EHsc /Yuheader.h /Fpheader.pch main.cpp /link header.obj
```

Comment: Why specify `header.obj` during compilation, surely it's only needed when linking?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat • the second command is a compile+link.  It'd need the `/c` to just be compile only, and in which case it wouldn't need `header.obj`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a project without precompiled headers.

[image]

Start by adding two new files: `precomp.h` and `precomp.cpp`:

[image]

`precomp.cpp` is simply this:

```
#include precomp.h
```

`precomp.h` is the header file with all the stuff you want precompiled - typically system and CRT header files:

```
#ifndef MY_PRECOMP_H
#define MY_PRECOMP_H

#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
// etc...

#endif
```

Update **every** non-header source files (that is, the .cpp source files) files in the project to have `#include "precomp.h"` as the **first** line before any other code.

[image]

Now, right click on the project title in the solution explorer:

[image]

And select "Properties" to bring up the project settings for the entire project:

[image]

Under C/C++ section of the project properties. Select "precompiled headers". Then enable the Precompiled Header option to be `Use (/Yu)`. Set the Precompiled Header File option to `precomp.h`.  Then click OK.

[image]

Final step.  Right click directly on `precomp.cpp` in your Solution Explorer and select "Properties".

[image]

This will display up a dialog similar to one you just saw for the project settings, but specific to this source file.

For this file's precompiled header options, select `Create (/Yc)` and the Precompiled Header option and `precomp.h` as the Header file option.

[image]

Now do a "clean" build followed by a full build. Precomp.cpp will get compiled first and generate the needed `.pch` file.  All the other source files upon getting compiled will pull in the precompiled header file.

Comment: thank you but I specifically said in the comments and in the question, I am not using visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

The solutions posted by Elijay and Minxin both work, however, in my case (and I am not entirely sure why) I had to reinstall the VS completely, and disabling the antivirus (I was getting strange threat warnings during compilation/running programs)

After that both of their solutions seems to produce a precompiled header that works